# Thread sleeps after few iterations while reading response of socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am developing an application in which i am writing and reading on a socket. However, it is only doing the task 11 times, then it sleeps.

**PollThread.java**

```
public class PollThread {

    static String result;
    private static Timer myTimer;
    static String ip = "192.168.1.19";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("PollThread");
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ClientThread cThread = new ClientThread(ip);
                String status = cThread.readStatus();
                System.out.println("Staus :: "+status);
            }
        }, 0, 2000);

    }
}
```

**ClientThread.java**

```
public class ClientThread {

    String byte_to_hex, swapped_result, result,ipAddr;
    public Socket s;
    public InputStream i;
    public OutputStream o;
    int status;

    public ClientThread(String ip) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.ipAddr=ip;

    }

    public int readStatus() {
        try {
            s = new Socket(ipAddr, 502);
            i = s.getInputStream();
            o = s.getOutputStream();

            byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = { (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00,
                    (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x19 };

            o.write(packet1);
            i.read(data1, 0, 1024);//Comment this
            byte_to_hex = bytesToHex(data1).substring(18, 26);

            char[] arr = byte_to_hex.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) {
                char temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
            }

            swapped_result = new String(arr);

            result = hexStringToNBitBinary(swapped_result, 32);

            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                if (result.charAt(i) == '1') {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            status = counter;

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
Staus :: 1
```

if I comment out `i.read(data1, 0, 1024);` then it works fine, but I need this line to get the result.

What could be the problem with this? Why it is only running 11 times?

**UPDATE-1**

```
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
Status :: 1
Reading status...
```

**Update 2**

I have also tried by adding this line  `cThread.start();`in `PollThread.java` file but yet result is same.

Comment: Why is ClientThread extending Thread?

Comment: @Sudhanshu because i want to this task in separate thread, in fact if i don't extend thread then also it gives me same result.

Comment: ..and why are you using a timer to continually create threads?  Why can you not just create one poll thread that loops?

Comment: @juned - you may be extending thread, but you never start it, so your class is running synchronously.

Comment: @Perception i have updated the code,now its not extending thread.

Comment: @juned - I suspect something on your server side is responsible for this observed behavior. If you have access to that, post the relevant code please.

Comment: @Perception there is no server side code, actually i am using simulator which opens `502` port on specified `ip` then i am writing and reading response on that socket.

Comment: So wheres the writing code?

Comment: @Perception this working fine without iterations but i want to read status continuously that's why using timer i am repeating this process. and why its working if i comment that line ?

Comment: It sounds like your `read` is blocked.  Are you sure there's more data to be read?

Comment: @SeKa yes, it always gives me room status, like how many equipments are on in particular room.

Comment: As other commenters have mentioned, your Timer is actually creating **multiple client connections**, one every two seconds, as opposed to a single connection that tests periodically.  It's quite possible that your "server simulator" has a max connect count of 10 or 11...

Comment: @yeah that could be possible, so how do i maintain this in single connection? should i close the socket each time after performing read and write ? but still i am confused if i comment out `i.read(data1, 0, 1024);` this line then thread won't goes in sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters have mentioned, your Timer is actually creating **multiple client connections**, one every two seconds, as opposed to a single connection that tests periodically. It's quite possible that your "server simulator" has a max connect count of 10 or 11.  Try moving your client connection outside your TimerTask, so it's not created each time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("PollThread");
    myTimer = new Timer();
    final ClientThread cThread = new ClientThread(ip);
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String status = cThread.readStatus();
            System.out.println("Staus :: "+status);
        }
    }, 0, 2000);
}
```

Sorry just noticed that you're creating a new Socket inside the readStatus method, which is essentially the same multiple connection problem.  Try moving that stuff into the Constructor, like:

```
public ClientThread(String ip) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.ipAddr=ip;

    try {
        s = new Socket(ipAddr, 502);
        i = s.getInputStream();
        o = s.getOutputStream();
    // ...
}

public int readStatus() {
    try {
        //s = new Socket(ipAddr, 502);
        //i = s.getInputStream();
        //o = s.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: Thanks but again same result :( . is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: @juned Sorry noticed your readStatus method was re-creating Socket each time.  See edit above that'll move that work to the Constructor.

Comment: yeah its working now, you are Awesome Thanks a lot, now just one question is this code is okay or not as we consider a performance, if is there any suggestion please let me know. thanks again

Comment: @juned It's difficult to answer a performance question w/o knowing your requirements, but overall Java's Timer does a pretty good job of managing resources.  My only other suggestion from a Java-coding-style perspective would be to move the Timer stuff you have out of `main` and into a method specifically named for that purpose.  This makes your code more portable, if you wanted to have `main` handle something else, for example.

Comment: @Thanks again, i have 7 this kind of room so i just move all common code in single class so now i think this solution will help me to improve the performance of my application.